# Is there a way to achieve two-way coupling in fluid simulations in Blender?

Tags: fluid-simulation

Usually in fluid simulations in Blender (I'm using Blender 2.90 and the fluid sim is done with Mantaflow), the Effectors can affect the fluid is the scene. However, the fluid cannot move any objects along with it.

For example, imagine a water damn that has just burst. When you release a huge volume of water, the liquid splashes around and this can be achieved in Blender. However, the huge inflow of water would also carry with it sediments from the soil or carry with it houses and trees and other debris. Can we simulate this phenomenon in Blender?